# PHP Mail function adding a <br /> in the middle of my message link

Tags: php, email

For learning purposes I am trying to make a PHP email verification/signup script. Everything is working as expected except for my email message. When sending the email, I include an `<a>` tag with a link to the verification page. Echoing the link displays the proper link, however when I receive the email there is a `<br />` in both the link and the display. The break is not in the middle of any of my variables, so I am unsure what is causing it.

My Code:

```
function SendVerificationEmail($email, $username, $verification) {
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Email Verification";
    $link = "http://localhost:80/verify.php?username=$username&validation=$verification";
    echo $link;
    $message = '

        Hello, ' . $username . '!' . '

        Thank you for signing up for Example.com!

        Please click the following link to verify your email. 
        <a href="' . $link. '">' . $link . '</a>
    ';

    $headers = "From:noreply@example.com\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

When I receive the email:

[Screenshot of Received Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsCGK.png)

Clicking the link then redirects me to:
`http://localhost:80/verify.php?username=gray&valid=<br%20/>ation=ed265bc903a5a097f61d3ec064d96d2e`

Which of course does not work, when I remove the `=<br%20/>` from the URL manually, everything works as expected.

Why is this break appearing in the email? It also seems to appear differently in the href and between the `<a>` and `</a>` tag.

SOLUTION:
Solved by adding Mime type to headers -
Changed headers to:
`$headers = "From:noreply@example.com\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";`

Comment: [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Tried `$link = "username=".urlencode($username)."&validation=".urlencode($verification);` and `href=http://localhost:80/verify.php?' . htmlentities($link) . '"` but I am still receiving the break mid url

Comment: is most likely the mta doing chunk split on the content as you not defined a mime type, set correct mime type, or don't use html in it and let the mail client add the link, look at the headers your see its actually gmail whos adding the <br>, it wont be in the actual email

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That did it, edited question to include solution

Comment: noice, your welcome. you might want it as `Content-type: text/html` if you intend to use html

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank for the heads up, if you want to leave an answer I can accept it